# Photoshop Script - Change specific text layer contents

Tags: javascript, scripting, photoshop

I have a photoshop script file which opens up a template psd file:

```js
var fileRef = new File("z:\psd.psd")
var docRef = app.open (fileRef)
```

Once this is open, i would like code which changes the text of a specific layer called "LAYER1" to "TEST".

I have researched and carried out numerous tests but i am having issues and errors with undefined variables.

Answer (score 1):

It it will be necessary to loop over all layers, (including layers within *Layer Groups*), to find your specific named *Text Layer* (e.g. *LAYER1*) before it's text content can be changed. To achieve this I recommend adding a custom function to your script.

The following code example will change the text content of the *Text Layer(s)* named *LAYER1* to *Hello World*.

```js
var fileRef = new File('z:\psd.psd');
var docRef = app.open(fileRef);

/**
  * Change text content of a specific named Text Layer to a new text string.
  *
  * @param {Object} doc - A reference to the document to change.
  * @param {String} layerName - The name of the Text Layer to change.
  * @param {String} newTextString - New text content for the Text Layer.
  */
function changeTextLayerContent(doc, layerName, newTextString) {
  for (var i = 0, max = doc.layers.length; i < max; i++) {
    var layerRef = doc.layers[i];
    if (layerRef.typename === "ArtLayer") {
      if (layerRef.name === layerName && layerRef.kind === LayerKind.TEXT) {
        layerRef.textItem.contents = newTextString;
      }
    } else {
      changeTextLayerContent(layerRef, layerName, newTextString);
    }
  }
}

changeTextLayerContent(docRef, 'LAYER1', 'Hello World');
```

---

#### Explanation

**Invoking the function:**

1. The last line of code above which reads:

   ```js
   changeTextLayerContent(docRef, 'LAYER1', 'Hello World');
   ```

   is where the `changeTextLayerContent` function gets invoked.

   We pass three arguments to the function as follows:

   - `docRef` - which is a object reference of the document in which to change its layers.
   - `'LAYER1'` - which is the name of the *Text Layer* to change its contents.
   - `'Hello World'` - which is the new text string (i.e. content) to apply to the *Text Layer* (in this case, to the *Text Layer* named `LAYER1`).
2. Let's say we were to invoke the function as follows:

   ```js
   changeTextLayerContent(docRef, 'MainTitle', 'The quick brown fox');
   ```

   This would set the text content of the *Text Layer* named `MainTitle` to *The quick brown fox*.

   Note: If your document/template included multiple *Text Layers* named `MainTitle` then they would all have their content changed to *The quick brown fox*.

**The `changeTextLayerContent` function:**

1. The function firstly utilizes a [`for` statement](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for) to loop over each top level *Layer* or *Group* which is listed in Photoshop's *Layers Palette.*
2. It then checks whether the layers `typename` is `ArtLayer`.

   - If its `typename` is `ArtLayer` it subsequently then checks the layers `name` equals the *layerName* you provided and whether the layers `kind` is equal to `LayerKind.TEXT`. If these conditional checks are both true, only then will it set the new text content for the *Text Layer* via the line which reads:

     ```js
     layerRef.textItem.contents = newTextString;
     ```
   - Alternatively, if the layers `typename` is not a `ArtLayer` then it must be a `LayerSet` (i.e. a Layer Group). In this scenario the function re-invokes itself via the line reading:

     ```js
     changeTextLayerContent(layerRef, layerName, newTextString);
     ```

     However, this time it passes the `layerRef` as the first argument, which causes the function to loop over all layers in the group/set and check them too.

---

Comment: Yes that's great thanks for your help much appreciated thank you.