# Javascript in Photoshop: changing text content increases font size

Tags: javascript, photoshop, extendscript, photoshop-script

I am using a Javascript function (found on this site) to change the content of a text layer:

```
var doc = app.activeDocument;

changeTextLayerContent(doc, "LAYER1", "new text");

function changeTextLayerContent(doc, layerName, newTextString) {
  for (var i = 0, max = doc.layers.length; i < max; i++) {
    var layerRef = doc.layers[i];
    if (layerRef.typename === "ArtLayer") {
      if (layerRef.name === layerName && layerRef.kind === LayerKind.TEXT) {
        layerRef.textItem.contents = newTextString;
      }
    } else {
      changeTextLayerContent(layerRef, layerName, newTextString);
    }
  }
}
```

This does change the text correctly. But it has a side effect of doubling the font size each time it is run.

Can anyone explain why please?

Thanks,
Antony

Comment: I guess this is from my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50574218/photoshop-script-change-specific-text-layer-contents/50588037#50588037). The only reason I can think why the text would increase in size is if the first character of the string is a space character, and that initial space character is set to a larger font size. Can you edit your question to provide steps for creating a document in which this issue can be reproduced. For example: _1)  Create new document. 2) Select type tool and click on the canvas. 3) Type the word 'Foobar' 4) Rename text layer to `LAYER1` etc_

Comment: Hi RobC,
Thanks for your reply. Yes it was your code.
I have just tried to replicate it, but now it's no longer doing it. All I can assume is that there was some glitch in my Photoshop yesterday, as it WAS doing it consistently, but now it isn't.
Thanks,
Antony

Comment: @AntonyMeadley Same problem. How do you solve it?